# Only some products using proper theme in Magento

Tags: magento, layout, view, themes, product

This has been very frustrating and I cannot figure it out.  I recognize the answer is most likely simple.

I have a my own package and all the desired pages except for some products are not using the desired theme product view layout.

Compared the data in mysql against a product that is displaying properly.  Both records match.

In Catalog/Manage products - I have performed a side by side comparison of the products in magento admin (including design).  both match.

In Catalog/Manage Categories - All categories set to apply to products and to use parent as default.

The default category is using my theme and applying to products.

Set the proper template in my local.xml file however this did not work.

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

In system/configuration/design I have the current package name set to my package for the Default Config.  Any children from there are checked to use default.

I tried several configurations with flushing cache and re indexing  just in case.

This is and example of the site the correct display (please note design not complete).
Page using correct Theme
Here is example of product using base theme
Page using BASE Theme

Any suggestions.  I understand that I could Manually select the desired template for each product and I would sooner jump off bridge.  I must be overlooking something.  Appreciate any advice.

Comment: *In Catalog/Manage products - I have performed a side by side comparison of the products in magento admin (including design). both match.* I think the problem is here. No special price, new product from date... ?

Comment: Thanks I have noticed that the new product from date is causing this in an few instances but not all.  I will check the the pricing as well.  Is there a default value for No special price?  I don't want to add 0 if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check to admin>product here each product can select difference type of custom design

[image]

Comment: Thanks Amit, If you noticed at the bottom of my long question I mentioned my desire to jump off a bridge before going that route.  But thanks for the reply!I appreciate it